# Is it possible to somehow import a Power BI Desktop model to a SSAS Tabular server?

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-2016, ssas-tabular

I have a model created using Power Bi Desktop and I want to import it to a SSAS Tabular server.

I'd an idea to start a SSAS Tabular project from a Power BI file (.pbix) similar to how it's possible to create a model from a Power Pivot file but there was no such option.

So, any other ideas?

---

### Little more details

**Power BI Desktop**

- Version: 2.46.4732.721 64-bit (May 2017)
- Internal SSAS: 14.0.1.253

**SSMS**

- 14.0.17099.0

**Exception**

```
Query (167, 36) The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 167, Offset 36, €.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in case you have SQL 2016. I found a blog post [here](http://biinsight.com/import-power-bi-desktop-model-ssas-tabular-2016/).

Requirements for this to work:

- SQL Server 2016 Tabular: You can download SQL Server 2016 Developer
  Edition for free.
- SQL Server Management Studio 2016
- SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015
- Power BI Desktop

I'll include the steps here for reference might the post ever get deleted:

1. Connect to Power BI Desktop model from SSMS 2016
2. Script the model
3. Modify the script
4. Execute the scripts on your on-premises instance of SSAS Tabular
   2016
5. Open the new SSAS Tabular database in SSDT 2016
6. Modify the model
7. Redeploy and process the model

Comment: I'll try it soon and let you know about the results. But thank you anyway

Comment: no, it's not working for me now. Probably because "now" Power BI Desktop uses SSAS 2017 as it's internal server, so the scripts I generate from its model do not work with Sql Server Tabular 2016 (that's my assumption). I've got "The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token...bla bla bla" exception while trying to execute genetared XMLA (JSON) script.

Comment: Can you share the exact error message that you received?

Comment: I've added little more details